# Is there a way to programatically manage drawing objects in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I would like my code to use drawings I put on the chart as "inputs" eg buy if the price closes in this rectangle I drew, or create/manipulate drawings eg create/move a line somewhere else etc...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to user drawn objects.

However, you can draw the objects yourself, and then use the getter functions to get the coordinates or values from those objects. You can even delete them whenever you like.

Please see [drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks, not the same objects, those are not manageable with mouse operations once created